# Visual Studio 2012 and Umbraco 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, umbraco

I am trying to install a clean Umbraco installation from NuGet in Visual Studio 2012, but when I am trying to run the code I get this error

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.BeginRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +16
   Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.<Init>b__8(Object sender, EventArgs e) +253
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Steps on how I do

1. New Project
2. ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application
3. Empty [Solution template]
4. Open Package Manager Console
5. Install nuget; PM> Install-Package UmbracoCms
6. Build Solution
7. Getting my error

*Note: I am installing version 7.1.1 and using Visual Studio 2012 Professional*

Comment: Sound like you opted NOT to overwrite global.asax (and/or web.config during install). Please try again and answer YES to overwrite web.config and global.asax.

Comment: I dont even get the chance to say Yes/No. Noticed this in the console when installing. 'Web.config' already exists. Skipping...
'Global.asax' already exists. Skipping...

Comment: Okay, also make sure to update to the latest version of NuGet, it helps a lot for some of these strange errors.

Comment: Thanks sebastiaan, already found the problem, and it was that I needed the latest version of NuGet! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the alternative solutions, 
I simply found out that the case it didn't work is because I needed to update Visual Studio 2012 for their new update, version 4.

So if anyone is getting this kind of errors trying to install Umbraco 7 through Visual Studio 2012

**Error 1**

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.BeginRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +16
   Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.<Init>b__8(Object sender, EventArgs e) +253
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

**Error 2**

```
The view '/umbraco/install/views/index.cshtml' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
/umbraco/install/views/index.cshtml
```

**Solution**

Update Visual Studio 2012 to version 4 (the newest)

1. Tools
2. Extensions and updates
3. Updates

Simply update everything there.

Comment: I am getting this error in production. What does Visual Studio update have to do with `umbraco` code?

Comment: Hello @ZainShaikh, sorry for answering this late. Hopefully you already figured out the correct answer. But it seems like if you don't have the updated version of NuGet Manager, there is a conflict between Umbraco and Visual Studio, some permissions and policies don't follow each other. Which means some of the files aren't transferred correct into visual studio.

Comment: No, the error was because of publishing. I published the site for deployment which caused the issue. Currently I am running unpublished site on staging server.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the hostprovider? If it is you hosting, what version of IIS do you use?

Comment: It's not about hosting, it happens on local machine as well. I am using IIS 7

Answer (score 5):

Before installing Umbraco cms to an existing VS MVC4 project you have to delete

1. all the config files in the App_Start folder,
2. web.config in the 'views' folder and
3. the global.asax files of the MVC project.

For more details please refer link 
http://umbraco.tv/videos/developer/fundamentals/surface-controllers/setting-up-the-vs-solution/

Comment: Greetings SAIndia, I tried to delete all the files before installing Umbraco. But unfortunately I am getting a new error! :( The view '/umbraco/install/views/index.cshtml' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
/umbraco/install/views/index.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

You can also setup an Umbraco 7 Application by following the steps below,

1. Install Microsoft WebMatrix (http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)
2. Open WebMatrix -> New -> App Gallery
3. Select Umbraco CMS and click next and follow the instructions.
4. Once done you can work on umbraco using the WebMatrix itself, or you can open the created website in Visual Studio to work.

Comment: Just don't use SQL Server CE due to this known issue http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4621